# Variable not updating outside of block

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, objective-c-blocks, parse-platform

So I have my code below. I'm trying to the order the mutable array in terms of score. I have assigned the score in a dictionary for the title of each pub. But when I'm calling the keyssortedbyvalue it's sorting them fine. As seen by the Logs (Below) but for some reason this change isn't being reflected in the variable sortedPubArray outside the block. Any ideas why?

NOTE: I have created a separate variable for sortedPubArray so it's easier to see it's not being reflected in the variable outside of the block.

```
//Method to get us the pubs for a specific user
+(NSMutableArray *)PubsForUser:(PFUser *)passedUser
{
//First things first let's create our array to represent the array of pubs which should be returned when our query finally executes (down there somewhere)
__block NSMutableArray *pubArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//And the sorted version, which we will ultimately return
__block NSMutableArray *sortedPubArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Get the user passed in so we can get there preferences
PFUser *currentUser = passedUser;
//Get all the keys into a local array so we can traverse through and find out what user likes
NSMutableArray *allTypes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[currentUser allKeys]];
//first we have to remove the username and email keys from the array
[allTypes removeObject:@"username"];
[allTypes removeObject:@"email"];

NSMutableArray *userTypes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Now traverse through array and if the type is set to true add it to our local userTypes array
//For each category in the user
for (NSString *typeKey in allTypes) {
    //If the user has selected this category as one of their choices
    if ([currentUser[typeKey]  isEqual: @YES]) {
        //Then add the category name (ie the key) to our local property representing the users choosen style of pubs
        [userTypes addObject:typeKey];
    }
}

//Create our array of queries
NSMutableArray *queryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Traverse through our array of user categories and create a query for each one.
for (NSString *style in userTypes) {

    //Set up Parse query
    PFQuery *pubQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Pub"];
    [pubQuery whereKey:style equalTo:@YES];

    //Add query to array of queries
    [queryArray addObject:pubQuery];

}



//Now create final query which will contain each of our subqueries
PFQuery *totalQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:queryArray];
[totalQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    //Do error checking
    if (error) {
        //Log out error message to user
        UIAlertView *queryErrorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Whoops!" message:@"Houston there's a problem! Try again in 5 minutes or drop us an email if this keep's happening at gordon@outerapp.com" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [queryErrorAlert show];
    } //It worked!
    else {
        //So now we have an array of PFObjects ie Pubs!
        [pubArray addObjectsFromArray:objects];

        //Now sort the array by number of hits, ie number of categories the same. So that the pub/club most tailored to the users tastes is top of the array

        //First create array to contain all pub categories so we're not comparing user's restaurant categories with the pub (this could crash the app as you can see below, we'd be trying toaccessing properties of the pub which don't exist
        NSMutableArray *pubTypes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[objects objectAtIndex:0] allKeys]];
        //And set up a dictionary to keep the score of each pub (score is how many of the same types it has as user
        NSMutableDictionary *pubScores = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


        //This requires us to iterate through the array assinging a value to the variable representing the "likeness" of the pub to the user. So the higher the score, the more hits
        for (PFObject *pub in pubArray) {

            int pubScore = 0;

            //So now we should calculate the total score, by iterating through and adding 1 each time it's true
            for (NSString *category in pubTypes) {

                //Test if the pub and the user's category choice is the same. ie this will iterate through student, theme, gastropub etc and everytime they are the same we add 1, and different -1
                if (pub[category] == currentUser[category]){

                    //They're the same so add to the score
                    pubScore++;

                } //If they're not the same
                else {

                    //Subtract one
                    pubScore--;

                }
            }

            //Now store the score of the pub in our dictionary
            [pubScores setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:pubScore] forKey:[pub objectForKey:@"PubName"]];
        }



        //And now finally simply sort the array by score (the first with the highest score), so that the pub with the best rating is at the top of the feed
        //To do this, we can use an inbuilt NSMutableDictionary method to output our keys in descending order of magnitude
        sortedPubArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[pubScores keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

            //If it's greater, put it above
            if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue])
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
            //If lower, then below
            if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue])
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;

            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;

        }]];

        NSLog(@"FinishedBlockLog: %@", sortedPubArray);
    }
}];

NSLog(@"FinishedMethodLog: %@", sortedPubArray);
return pubArray;
}
```

Logs:

2013-11-09 16:35:27.722 Outer[5037:70b] FinishedMethodLog: (
)

2013-11-09 16:35:27.723 Outer[5037:70b] Variable assigned to the return of the method: (
)

2013-11-09 16:35:27.925 Outer[5037:70b] FinishedBlockLog: (
    TestPub,
    "Waxy O'Connors",
    "The Ark",
    "The Counting House",
    Radio
)

2013-11-09 16:35:32.590 Outer[5037:70b] Button I've created to log out variable which has the return of the method assigned to it: (
)

So we can see that when the block is finished, and I'm logging out sortedPubArray when that happens, it still isn't reflected in sortedPubArray outside of the block. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I access a \_\_block variable, after the block has completed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572202/how-can-i-access-a-block-variable-after-the-block-has-completed)

Comment: You'll have to grasp the concept of *asynchronous* operations :-)

Comment: No I know that it's not going to complete immediately, but it doesn't update it at all. No matter how long I wait

Comment: How do you use the return value of `PubsForUser`? - In any case, you should update the UI in the completion block.

Comment: I'll be using it to get the data from each of the pubs. But of course not until it's actually complete. So for now, there's no code executed on it. The last log is called every time I hit a button, and it's output is just the variable which is assigned to the return value of this method. I would think the variable should update when the block is complete as it's simply a pointer to the array? I appreciate your help Martin. Yeah the reason I'm not updating the UI is this isn't inside a viewController. It's just a model class from which my VC is getting the information.

Comment: The "usual" solution is to call `PubsForUser` with block argument. The block is called from the completion handler. Inside the block you update the UI.

Comment: I take what you meant to be this: __block NSMutableArray *returnArray =  [PubFinder PubsForUser:[PFUser currentUser]]; but that didn't get it working unfortunately. I then assigned that to a pubArray property of the class and even after the block had finished it didn't update the array

Answer (score 3):

First, there is no reason to use `__block` for `pubArray`.  You aren't changing either variable in the block (calling a method on the object that the variable refers to *does not change the variables value*).  For `sortedPubArray`, there is no reason to assign an empty mutable array to that variable as you just re-assign to said variable later in your code anyway.

BTW: `PubsForUser:` should be `pubsForUser:`.  Methods always start with lowercase letters.

The real source of your problem, though, is your concurrency model.   You are executing something in the background, but expecting the result to be immediately available in the foreground.   Consider your log statements:

```
2013-11-09 16:35:27.722 Outer[5037:70b] FinishedMethodLog: ( )

2013-11-09 16:35:27.723 Outer[5037:70b] Variable assigned to the return of the method: ( )

2013-11-09 16:35:27.925 Outer[5037:70b] FinishedBlockLog: ( TestPub, "Waxy O'Connors", "The Ark", "The Counting House", Radio )
```

Note the time stamps;  your `pubsForUserMethod:` is finishing at `16:35:27.722`, but the background execution doesn't finish until `16:35:27.925`, ~200ms later.

You need to either execute this synchronously or put a callback at the end of the background block that tells your main thread that stuff is ready (most likely).

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [myUIThingy youManYourStuffIsReady: sortedPubArray]; });
```

Note that simply tossing stuff into the background for execution is not a very good concurrency model.   You need to think very carefully about your data, synchronization points, and coherency between threads.

---

Now, if you *really are* using the returned `pubsArray` (which begs the question of why `sortedPubsArray` exists at all) and still wondering why your UI state doesn't update...

... your UI state won't update by itself.  You still need a callback in that background task that lets the UI know that it should, say, reload the table view that is displaying the contents of said array.

And you need to make sure that nothing is copying `pubsArray` and tossing the original value.   Far better to make `pubsForUser:` return `(void)` and potentially take a block as an argument that gets executed when all is said and done.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I'm not actually returning pubArray. That was just left in from testing, and I mustn't have updated it when I copied+pasted it into stackoverflow. I'm not wanting to update the UI just now anyway, I will eventually but I don't understand why, even after the block is complete, the array is not updated outside of it. So you can see with my FinishedBlockLog that even after the block is complete, the next log (5s later) which is printing out the variable assigned to the return value of our method (ie sortedPubArray, which is what it should be in my code) is still empty array.

Comment: @Gordon Make sure you are actually looking at the same array;  `NSLog(@"Array %p %@", array, array);`.

Comment: Yeah, so this is my assignment `self.pubArray = [PubFinder pubsForUser:[PFUser currentUser]];` and this is the log called `NSLog(@"Button I've created to log out variable which has the return of the method assigned to it: %@", self.pubArray);`

Comment: Okay so I've managed to get it working by actually moving the code into a method in my VC and assigning the sortedPubArray directly to self.pubArray when the block is complete. I don't understand why it wasn't working before, I assumed self.pubArray would simply be a pointer to the actual Array? Maybe not, anyway thanks for your time bbum, much appreciated.

Comment: `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *pubArray;`

Comment: @Gordon You need to print the address of the arrays at all the logging sites.  More likely than not, you have a different instance than you think.