# Setting block value in Objective-C using Parse

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com in my objective-c code to simply check to see if a record is there and return true if it is and false if it's not, here's my code:

```
- (BOOL)userExists:(NSString*) email{

    __block BOOL exists = NO;

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
    [query whereKey:@"email" equalTo:email];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d objects.", objects.count);
            // Do something with the found objects




            if (objects.count > 0) {
                exists = YES;
                NSLog(@"Objects > 0");
            }else{
                exists = NO;
                NSLog(@"Objects = 0");
            }




        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            //NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);


        }
    }];





    return exists;


}
```

This method for some reason is returning NO, even though there is a row that contains that email address I'm looking for.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Or [How can I access a __block variable, after the block has completed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572202/how-can-i-access-a-block-variable-after-the-block-has-completed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your block is working in the background, thus, your method is returning the value NO before your block completes the work.