# Variable value null after if statement

Tags: objective-c, url, if-statement, nsstring, objective-c-blocks

Here i get data from a url.

I declare my NSString in the header file of my view controller

```
@property NSString *contentsOfUrl;
```

then i get the contents of a url and assign it to this string

```
-(void)press

{

NSURLSession *session1 = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

[[session1 dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/soc/code/2222"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

if (((NSHTTPURLResponse*) response).statusCode == 200) {

        if (data) {

           contentsOfUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];   
        }

    }

}] resume];


NSLog(@"%@", contentsOfUrl);


 }
```

For some reason my variable is null. However when i put the NSLog in the if statement it has the correct data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I access a \_\_block variable, after the block has completed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572202/how-can-i-access-a-block-variable-after-the-block-has-completed)

Answer (score 1):

This is because contentsOfUrl is assigned inside the completion handler that is called asynchronous.

So your block:

```
^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

if (((NSHTTPURLResponse*) response).statusCode == 200) {

        if (data) {

           contentsOfUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];   
        }

    }

}
```

is getting called after the NSLog line.
If you want to do something with this data do it right from inside the block

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way I use the data from outside the block?

Comment: Data is captured when entering the block.. so when you went into the block the data is snapshoted.. if you want to change a value in and outside the block the same time, you need to use the __block syntax. for example __block NSNumber *number = @3; with this you can change number in and outside the block just if there would be no async call at all.. I would recommend reading a bit about blocks in objective-c

Comment: So short answer yes.. also contentsOfUrl is accessible from outside.. in this case you just don't know when the block will be executed. So If you rely on contentsOfUrl you should invoke the corresponding method from inside the block..